# Multivariate model with two variables

Tags: regression, missing-data, matrix, model-evaluation

Consider the following problem: there are two variables, $X_1,X_2$ with some latent connection. Given a training data, $(x^i_1,x^i_2)_{i=1}^m$, we need to come up with a model that predicts $x^i_1$ given $x^i_2$ and vice versa. That is, in the future we will receive with probability $0.5$ the value of $X_1$ and and seek to predict the value of $X_2$.

Say we are restricted to linear models (i.e. lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

1. What are good evaluation measures for this problem? my initial thought is to measure the success of any such model as the [perpendicular distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) from a point to to the line. For instance, if the model is $X_1=aX_2+b$ and the given point is $(x_1,x_2)$, then the error is $\left| { a \cdot x_1 - x_2 +b \over \sqrt{a^2+1}} \right|$.
2. It seems that this probelm is a special case of [matrix completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_completion). However, the RMSE measure examines the completion of the missing values, and here we have some information about what we will miss.

Any comments?

Thanks!